# Subsets of set satisfying open set condition

Tags: geometry, fractals

Suppose an iterated function system of similarity transformations $S_1, S_2, \dotsc, S_k:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}^n$ (with unique invariant set $F$) satisfies the open set condition for some non-empty bounded open set $O\subset \mathbb{R}^n$, so that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i(O)\subset O$$ with the union disjoint.

If $U\subset O$ is open and arbitrary, I would like to prove that $U$ is also a suitable choice in the OSC, so that $$\bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i(U)\subset U.$$

Clearly $\bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i(U)\subset \bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i(O)\subset O$, but is it the case that the setup necessarily implies $\bigcup_{i=1}^kS_i(U)\subset U$ with this union disjoint?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The statement is false.  Consider the IFS on $\mathbb R$ consisting of the similarities $S_1(x)=x/2$ and $S_2(x)=x/2+1/2$.  The open unit interval $(0,1)$ verifies OSC for this IFS. However, no interval of the form $(a,b)$ with $0<a<b<1$ will verify OSC.

Comment: How about the case where the similarities satisfy $S_i(A)\subset A$ for any set $A$ where $S_i$ is defined? Then if $U\subset O$ where $O$ is the original set in the OSC, immediately $\bigcup_{i=1}^k S_i(U)\subset U$, but is the union necessarily disjoint? I can't find a counter-example for this.

Comment: So, say, in your example, if $S_1(x)=\frac{x}{2}$ and $S_2(x)=\frac{x}{2} +\frac{1}{2}a$ for $x\in (a,b)$.

Comment: @skipdivided You want $S_i(A) \subset A$ for *any* set $A$ and independent of $i$?  Seems like quite a strong assumption. In fact, if you have at least two different contractions with distinct fixed points, then I don't think this condition can be arranged.

Comment: Sorry, I rather meant the condition that $S_i(U)\subset U$ for any $U\subset O$ where $O$ is the set in the OSC; not $S_i(A)\subset A$ for any set $A\subset \mathbb{R}^n$. Would the modification I gave of your example not satisfy this with $O=(a,b)$ for any $(a,b)\subset \mathbb{R}$? In which case $S_1((a',b'))$ and $S_2((a',b'))$ would indeed be disjoint for any $(a',b')\subset (a,b)$, and I think this property does extend to the general case?

Comment: @skipdivided If $S_i(O)\cap S_j(O)$ is empty and $U\subset O$, then certainly $S_i(U)\cap S_j(U)$ will be empty as well. So, if $U$ happens to satisfy $S_i(U)\subset U$ for each $i$, then $U$ will verify OSC as well.  But, again, I think this is quite unusual and certainly not likely to happen for *all* open $U\subset O$. On the contrary, if you have at least two different contractions with distinct fixed points, then you will *always* be able to find an open ball $B$ of sufficiently small radius so that $B\not\supset S_i(B)\cup S_j(B)$.